# Retrieve UGC Posts through LinkedIn V2 API got ClassCastException error

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve a list of UGC posts by calling the following API

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List%28urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A[ORG_ID]%29
```

**[ORG_ID]** is id of my organization. Then I got this error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.linkedin.data.DataComplex",
    "status": 500
}
```

I've already authorized to use API V2 and include `X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0` in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues with this too, the parens on the `authors` query param shouldn't be encoded.

I.e., try:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A[ORG_ID])

Comment: I tried this var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A"+newcompanyid+")";    
. But, I'm still getting the error. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with the URL mentioned https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A[ORGANISATION ID]) and it works but make sure you set the header.
`X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0`

I had to do this manually however since postman apparently doesn't work and perhaps other http tools are having similar issues.
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5752

The error returned by postman is the following or if you forget to include the header above: `{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"java.lang.ClassCastException","status":500}`