# Field Value validation failed in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/authors] in linkedIn API V2

Tags: linkedin-api

There is a [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697531/retrieve-ugc-posts-through-linkedin-v2-api-got-classcastexception-error)

I tried the solution which was given in the answer.

I tried multiple scenarios, but I keep getting the below error:

URL1:

```
var companyid = '123456789';
var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List("+ encodeURIComponent(companyid)+")";
```

Log of the `url` returns below url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A123456789)
```

URL2:

```
var companyid = '123456789';
var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List("+(companyid)+")";
```

Log of the `url` returns below url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn:li:organization:123456789)
```

Here are the permissions I have requested for authentication:

```
r_liteprofile
r_emailaddress
w_member_social
rw_organization_admin
rw_organization
r_organization_social
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the header information about the V2 protocol version ad described [in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#retrieve-ugc-posts):

> All API requests are represented in protocol 2.0.0 and require the
>   header X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0.

So if you made the API Call Like:

```
curl  -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A123456789)&oauth2_access_token=<access_token>"
```

You will retrieve some data, like:

```
{"elements":[],"paging":{"total":0,"count":10,"start":0,"links":[]}
```

Hope this help

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the solution. I was confused because other v2 requests are working fine without `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` in the header.