# Fetch company posts from linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch the posts of the company from the api, I have already applied to the marketing development platform and it was approved. I already got the token with the scope: r_organization_social and I'm calling the /shares api:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{company_ID}&sharesPerOwner=100&count=25&sharesPerOwner=10
```

But I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 25,
        "links": [
            {
                "type": "application/json",
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/shares?count=25&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{company_ID}&q=owners&sharesPerOwner=10&sharesPerOwner=100&start=0"
            }
        ],
        "total": 242
    },
    "elements": []
}
```

I tried to change the query params and it's still the same

Comment: According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177366/field-value-validation-failed-in-parameter-data-processing-exception-while-proc), it could be because the header X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 is missing. In my case, if I include it, I get another error "Invalid value type for parameter owners"', which seems to be a common issue already reported ([git issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/1215)). Please let me know if you find any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

This end-point worked for me:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<ID_ORGANIZATION>)
```

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?tabs=http#sample-request-6

Comment: the ugcPost endpoint is the correct choice since LinkedIn devs said that the share endpoint is going to be deprecated in future (as said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares#ugc-post-api))

Comment: but it only shows 100 random posts. what if I want to get all the number of posts ? i.e., 469 ?

Comment: @sodmzs1 you have to go to through the pagination. If you use that endpoint you get a response like that:

"paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": [
            {
                "type": "application/json",
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&start=10&count=10&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<ID_ORGANIZATION>)"
            }
        ],
        "total": 13
    },

 ...

where "total" indicates the totals posts. To see all, instead, you have to follow "href" endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've no access to the linkedin API and couldn't test. But these are some things I noticed:

Your url contains two times the paramater *sharesPerOwner*, try removing one.

In the docs it's recommended to set the sharesPerOwner to 1000 and the count to 50. I'd also include the start paramater, just to make sure:
Maybe try something like this:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:{id}&sharesPerOwner=1000&count=50&start=0
```

From the api-docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http#find-shares-by-owner): "Note that the pagination excludes UGC and Direct Sponsored Content (DSC) posts". Make sure that the owner you are testing contains posts.

If this doesn't work. Could you provide some information on how you are sending the request? Have you tried accessing other parts of the api?